# JQPlot - Get rid of time ticks?

Tags: javascript, jqplot

I am using JQPlot to graph usage over time of an application. Currently I am trying to make each tick generated using DateAxisRenderer, which works wonderfully, except that because the dates hold data down to the millisecond, there are two identical ticks for each day, one representing 12:00AM and one 12:00PM. How can I consolidate these to make it just one tick for each day? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this inside your `xaxis` preferences block:

```
tickInterval:'1 day'
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe [tickInterval](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-core-js.html#Axis.tickInterval) will do what you want:

> tickInterval
>
> number of units between ticks.  Mutually exclusive with numberTicks.

I have not tried it but I'd imagine you'd want it to be 86400000 (the number of milliseconds in one day).